# need to make sure my ajax script is set up right

Tags: ajax

ajax code:

```
try { 
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
} 
catch(ee) { 
    try { 
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
    } 
    catch(e) { 
        try { 
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
        } 
        catch(E) { 
            xmlhttp = false; 
        } 
    } 
} 
div_base = ""; 
valor = 0; 

function abre(arquivo,metodo,div) { 
    div_base = div; 
    valor++; 
    xmlhttp.open(metodo,arquivo+"?valor="+valor); 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=response 
    xmlhttp.send(null) 
} 

function response() { 
    nova_div = div_base; 
    document.getElementById(nova_div).innerHTML="<div>Loading...</div>" 
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) { 
        document.getElementById(nova_div).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText 
    } 
}
```

html code:

```
<form> 
    <select name="menu" style="width:400px; height:25px;">
        <option>Change Theme:</option>
        <option></option>
        <option onclick="javascript: abre('Chat_Themes/Default.html','GET','response2');">Default - Shadow Hunters</option> 
        <option onclick="javascript: abre('Chat_themes/Custom.html','GET','response2');">Custom - Shadow Hunters</option>  
    </select> 
</form>
<br />
<div id="response2"></div>
```

i changed the "div = responce" to "div = responce2" without changing the ajax code at the top, im not sure if i have to change the ajax code or not or i can leave it and it works fine the way it is, but it does not work on google chrome idk if its just google chrome being retarded, but it works in ff and ie just fine, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try indenting your code: you'll find that your try-catch statements don't have matching braces. You can also try a Javascript-validating service like [jshint](http://jshint.com/), but indenting should come first.

You might want to consider using a third-party library which already has cross-browser AJAX capability, like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).